# Почему после рестарта сервера БД оказывается в состоянии shutdown?

Tags: sql, windows, oracle, dba

В наличии Windows сервер ,Oracle 11g и 3 базы данных.

После рестарта сервера стартует все 3 службы, 2 БД находятся в состоянии `Open`, а одна в статусе `shutdown` и приходится стартовать ее руками из `sqlplus`. 
Подскажите, куда посмотреть и как настроить БД на автоматический старт после перезагрузки сервера?

Можно написать скрипт, который стартанет БД автоматически при запуске сервера. 
Но 2 другие БД стартуют автоматически, и хотелось бы понять, что я упустил.

Comment: Standalone или RAC? Grid Infrastructure испоьзуется?

Comment: нет,  не используются

Comment: A сервис стартует? Если да, то смотрите в виндовых логах, если нет, поставте его в авто. Если ничего не помогает, то  как в уже предложеном ответе.

Comment: Да, сервис стартует автоматически

Comment: @lDrakonl Если сервис сартует, а толку от этого мало, то надо было посмотреть ключик: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\oracle_home
ORA_<SID>_AUTOSTART`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте или измените сервис при помощи [ORADIM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e10845/create.htm#i1006533):

Создание сервиса:

```
oradim -NEW -SID <ORACLE_SID> -STARTMODE auto -PFILE C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\admin\prod\pfile\init.ora
```

Изменение сервиса:

```
oradim -EDIT -SID <ORACLE_SID> -STARTMODE auto -PFILE C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\admin\prod\pfile\init.ora
```

Для Windows ключ отвечающий за старт можно найти в ветке реестра:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\oracle_home ORA_<SID>_AUTOSTART
```

Comment: Нет никакой возможности включить автоматический старт на уровне файла параметров или чего то такого? Не хочется пересоздавать сервис.

Comment: @lDrakonl, а что в логах? Если сервис стартует, он должен что-то писать в логи.

Comment: Сервис просто создан со startmode manual